# How do I know when to use -тся or -ться in a verb

Tags: грамматика, tense

The title pretty much says it all. It's a very common mistake which (unfortunately) even many native speakers make.

Is there a rule to unambiguously decide should I end this verb with `-тся` or `-ться`?

Comment: Why do you consider this a question if you know the answer?

Comment: I suppose this is the purpose of private beta, to pre-populate the site with questions (and answers) that are likely to arise.

Comment: @bonomo http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: oh, I apologize, here are some ideas for questions you might want to consider adding here http://gramota.ru/, http://www.alphadictionary.com/rusgrammar/

Comment: @bonomo: or maybe these links should go straight to the FAQ

Comment: I agree about adding a link to http://gramota.ru/ to the FAQ. Who can edit it?

Comment: One of my friends would really benefit from this question.

Comment: There's also a site http://tsya.ru ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are four cases when you put `ь` in verb suffixes:

- Infinitive: умывать(ся), беречь(ся).
- Second person singular present or future tense: умываешь(ся), бережёшь(ся).
- After all consonants except `й` and `г` (ляг(те)) with imperative mood: исправь(те).
- Suffixes following a vowel: вернусь, вернитесь, вернулись, вернувшись.

In all other cases, there is no `ь`.

The best way is to ask a question... If it ends in `т`, it's `тся`, if in `ть`, then it's `ться`:

- Я собираюсь - что сдела**ть**? - прогуляться.
- Сейчас - что делае**т**? - строится новый район.
- Все, что может - что дела**ть**? - портиться, обязательно - что сделае**т**? -
  испортится!

Comment: Good examples! :)

Comment: Yes, exactly how I learned it!

Comment: That's how it's taught in Russian schools.

Answer (score 5):

The key here is to ask a question that this verb answers.

If the question is "what is it doing?", then the ending should be `-тся` (делается, пишется, причесывается, ...)

If the question is "what to do?", then it's `-ться` (делаться, писаться, причесываться, ...)

Answer (score 4):

It's a big problem ;-) and there's whole site dedicated to that question:
http://tsya.ru/

Comment: Haha, nice website :) Although one could argue that this ought to be a comment rather than an answer. +1 anyway

Comment: I suppose, the whole site deserves whole answer ;-)

Comment: i always consider these rules as a good tool to 'remember recapitulation technique'